# SQLite CRUD Issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am attempting to implement a somewhat simple SQLite database based off the vogella tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html.

The database below is very simple and I have only 1 column COLUMN_TOPIC, which I set to TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL.

The issue I am having is in regards to the CRUD operations that I have laid out. I am unable to retrieve a single Topic Object using the line

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TopicDBHelper.TABLE_TOPICS, allColumns,
      TopicDBHelper.COLUMN_TOPIC + " = " + "'" + topic + "'", null, null, null, null); if (cursor
      != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { newTopic = cursorToTopic(cursor);
```

and I am not able to retrieve all topics using the getAllTopics() method. The values being returned are NULL

From what I have found it is possible to use a String or Text as a primary key, although not necessarily recommended.

**Is there anything wrong the way I am trying to access the database? or is there an issue with the SQL that I am trying to execute?**

This is how I am calling the associated DB Actions

```
MQTTServiceDelegate.addTopicToDB(this, "ALL");
MQTTServiceDelegate.getAllTopicsFromDB(this);
```

and here is the **MQTTServiceDelegate**

```
    public static void addTopicToDB(Context context, String topicName) {
    TopicsDataSource datasource = new TopicsDataSource(context);
    datasource.open();
    datasource.createTopic(topicName);
    datasource.close();
  }

  public static void removeTopicFromDB(Context context, String topicName) {
    TopicsDataSource datasource = new TopicsDataSource(context);
    datasource.open();
    datasource.deleteTopic(topicName);
    datasource.close();
  }

  public static void getAllTopicsFromDB(Context context){
    TopicsDataSource datasource = new TopicsDataSource(context);
    datasource.open();
    datasource.getAllTopics();
    datasource.close();
  }
```

**TopicDBHelper**

```
  public static final String TABLE_TOPICS = "topics";
  public static final String COLUMN_TOPIC = "topic";
  public static final String COLUMN_TOPIC_ID = "topic_id";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "topics.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_TOPICS + "(" + COLUMN_TOPIC
      + " text primary key not null);";



  public TopicDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TopicDBHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TOPICS);
    onCreate(db);  
  }
```

**TopicDataSource**

```
// Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private TopicDBHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = {TopicDBHelper.COLUMN_TOPIC};

  public TopicsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new TopicDBHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }

  public void createTopic(String topic) {
    Topic newTopic = null;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TopicDBHelper.COLUMN_TOPIC, topic);
    /*
     * Cursor cursor = database.query(TopicDBHelper.TABLE_TOPICS, allColumns,
     * TopicDBHelper.COLUMN_TOPIC + " = " + "'" + topic + "'", null, null, null, null); if (cursor
     * != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { newTopic = cursorToTopic(cursor); cursor.close();
     * Log.e("CURSOR", newTopic.get_topicName());
     * 
     * } Log.e("CURSOR", "" + newTopic.get_topicName());
     */
    /* return newTopic; */

  }

  public void deleteTopic(String topicName) {
    database.delete(TopicDBHelper.TABLE_TOPICS, TopicDBHelper.COLUMN_TOPIC + " = " + topicName,
        null);
  }

  public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
    List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<Topic>();

     Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TopicDBHelper.TABLE_TOPICS, null);

    /*
     * Cursor cursor = database.query(TopicDBHelper.TABLE_TOPICS, allColumns, null, null, null,
     * null, null);
     */

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Topic topic = cursorToTopic(cursor);
        Log.e("GET ALL TOPICS", "" + topic.get_topicName());
        topics.add(topic);
        cursor.moveToNext();
      }
      // make sure to close the cursor
      cursor.close();
    }
    return topics;
  }

  private Topic cursorToTopic(Cursor cursor) {
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.set_topicName(cursor.getString(1));
    return topic;
  }
```

Comment: when doing INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs you need to be in a transaction...and COMMIT that transaction if you find everything ok. You don't need a transaction on SELECTs.

Comment: [`"'" + topic + "'"` <= this is so bad](http://xkcd.com/327/) (and the exploits are not the only cause why it is so bad)

Answer (score 0):

Column indexing in a cursor is zero-based. Since there is only one column, `getString(1)` in your `cursorToTopic()` refers to a column that doesn't exist, and a `null` can be returned.

Change it to `getString(0)` instead.

There are a number of other issues with the code; covering them all is possibly too broad for Stack Overflow.